# elasticsearch: Get all documents that share the same top-most ancestor

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get all documents that share the same top-most ancestor, where one child can be the parent, grandparent, grand grandparent etc. of multiple docs.

So let's say I have a structur like this (borrowed from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/parent-join.html):

```
   (parent)
   question
    /    \
   /      \
comment  answer
(child)  (child)
```

In code:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "mapping.single_type": true
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "my_join_field": {
          "type": "join",
          "relations": {
            "question": ["answer", "comment"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, one can answer comments and comment answers theoretically forever. So say I have a question, that is structured like this:

```
                               (id: 1)
                               question
                              /        \
                             /          \
                        answer          answer
                       (id: 5)          (id: 8)
                       /     \              |
                      /       \             |
                   comment  answer        answer
                  (id: 15) (id: 12)      (id: 9)
                  /    \        |          /   \  
                 /      \       |         /     \ 
              answer  answer  comment  answer  answer 
             (id: 16)(id: 17) (id: 19) (id: 10)(id: 11)
```

How do I get all the documents (ids 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19), only knowing id 9?

Comment: Since you're trying to get all children and parents of a given document, I don't see how the branch below document 5 is relevant to the document 9.

Comment: Well in my case it is very relevant, as I would like to get all documents associated with doc 9. The reason being that there are many more branches of documents, then the one shown that are not connected (and they are not relevant to doc 9).

Comment: So, to sum up, you basically need to get all documents that are part of the same tree as the doc 9, i.e. all documents that share the same top-most ancestor as doc 9.

Comment: Yes - that is exactly what I need (and have changed the question base on your input)!

Comment: The easiest thing you could do is to include a new field containing the id of the top-most ancestor in each document of the tree. That way you can easily retrieve all documents with that id.

Comment: Is there any other way? The thing is, that data is updated continuously, so say there is a new comment to id 11, I would have to load in doc 11, get the top-level-id, save that to the new doc and index that into ES. It is not impossible, but was just wondering if there was any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an excerpt from Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relations.html):**

```
Four common techniques are used to manage relational data in Elasticsearch:

Application-side joins
Data denormalization
Nested objects
Parent/child relationships 

Often the final solution will require a mixture of a few of these techniques.
```

As **Val** suggested you may implement Application-side joins by introducing two fields: "top_most_ansestor" and "parent". That's a very reasonable and simple solution as it doesn't require Elasticsearch join field.

However, you may want to combine techniques.

If you want to use join field then you can consider defining a top most ancestor as a parent of all children, grandchildren, etc and maintain your tree hierarchy in your application. From Elasticsearch point of view you will have a shallow but wide tree (single parent with many leafs)

```
question(id 1): [ids 1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 19]
```

Retrieval of the whole tree will be done with a single request. You application will see your documents differently, as you described above: deep tree. E.g. for document 9 you'll have

```
_id:9 {"parent":8,"text":"some text", "type":"answer"}
```

What technique you should use depends on other requirements and your preferences. The simpler the better.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I ended up using @Val suggestion and added a field called parent_id. For every child I call the parent_id of the parent and saves that in parent_id. This leaves me with two additional possibilities, 1: I can skip using parent/child relationship (as it is depreciated from 6.0+) and in can collapse on parent_id and thus get stats on, how many docs I have in a tree (etc.).